# Angular - Ngx Charts & d3 - Unique color for each pie chart slice

Tags: angular, d3.js, ngx-charts

I'm looking for a unique color generation implementation using the `ngx-charts` and `d3.js` libraries.

More precisely, I need a unique color for each slice of my pie/doughnut chart. This is an important requirement as the chart data is dynamic and we don't know for sure how many pie slices there will be.

Ideally, I would like to have 50 to 100 unique colors belonging to the same color scheme. If we do have more data slices than that amount of colors, we could probably think of repeating colors.

I'm working with Angular, so I would create a `Color Manager` service that would deal with the color generation for each slice. In my head it would look something like:

```
export class ColorManagerService {
    private colorScale; // d3 color scheme? ideally 50-100 unique colors of a scheme
    private usedColors; // set of keys/colors to keep track

    getColor(chartKey: string): string {
        // generate a color
        // check if color is already in use
        // if not, return this color
        // else, create a new color
    }
}
```

Any suggestions/examples (preferably with d3.js) for this implementation are welcome.

Comment: i think you can use this lib to generate the colors https://github.com/gka/chroma.js,
then another idea is order the color of the slices to have a not similar color on the left and the right, mix the  colors of the slice of pie , for have a more visual easy reading , because when you have the case of 100 color , i will be probably have similar tones of colors, so intercalate this tones i think will be a good idea

Comment: I was hoping for a `d3.js` solution to this. I think for now while I don't have an actual color generator I will just save some hardcoded color values, which should all be unique so as not worry about left and right slices, but I appreciate your suggestion.